# Switch between development and production in a java webapp

Tags: java, intellij-idea

My team develops a `Vaadin` web application. When we are giving a release for production, we have to manually make several changes in few files before building the war file. For an example, we have to change `log4j` settings in `log4j2.xml` and set vaadin `productionMode` to `true` in `web.xml`.

We are using Intellij IDEA for development. We build the webapp using Maven

Is there a better way to keep two build modes so that we can easily switch between production and development mode?

Comment: Checkout Maven profiles. http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your intention is to generate different deliverables of each one of your environments, a posible solution is to use Maven profiles.

http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html

If you define different profiles with a different set of resources for each one, say 'AVE', 'UAT', 'NFT', whatever, you can then call Maven with a designated profile in order to generate the application you need

```
mvn clean deploy -P AVE
mvn clean deploy -P UAT
```

etc.

If you don't want to keep different versions of your *.properties and web.xml and maintain all of them (which would be a burden and quite error-prone), you can also use profiles, but combine it with filtering (http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html) in order to keep only 1 copy of each properties, web.xml, etc. in your code. This way you can have some properties like 'productionMode' you mention depending on properties defined in the AVE, UAT, NFT, etc. profiles in your pom.xml.